# T-SQL Looking for select on Time FROM and TO based on VARCHAR (version) selection

Tags: t-sql

Looking for solution on my problem.
Have table that in my example contain only 2 columns. 
Column varVersion show version number of our Application. 
Column dateLoginTime show when customer last time login to the application.

My first thought was to just create a Max date, order by date and group by varVersion. This seems to work just fine until users start using old application.

On my example you can see that user use version 2.1.3 and than move back to 1.1.8. With max time it look like he is using this version for 6 days. When I looked on the data he use this version only for 5 minutes (mistake).

Max:

```
varVersion |    dateLoginTime
2.1.4      |    2018-03-13 11:31:26.893
1.1.8      |    2018-03-07 16:40:21.060
2.1.3      |    2018-02-28 12:26:52.760
2.1.2      |    2018-02-15 12:35:42.707
1.1.6      |    2018-01-23 15:01:46.410
```

I'm looking to create new field and see when the app was used from to. But failing to get correct results. Tried min/max/over but still wrong.

Min/Max result:

```
varVersion  |FROM                    |TO
2.1.4       |2018-02-28 22:45:48.687 |2018-03-13 11:31:26.893
2.1.3       |2018-02-26 12:16:41.907 |2018-02-28 12:26:52.760
2.1.2       |2018-02-14 19:56:11.837 |2018-02-15 12:35:42.707
1.1.8       |2018-01-24 12:19:06.933 |2018-03-07 16:40:21.060
1.1.6       |2018-01-08 16:54:46.780 |2018-01-23 15:01:46.410
```

Expected Result

```
version |FROM                    |TO
2.1.4   |2018-03-07 16:45:10.207 |2018-03-13 11:31:26.893
1.1.8   |2018-03-07 16:40:21.060 |2018-03-07 16:45:10.207
2.1.4   |2018-02-28 22:45:48.687 |2018-03-07 16:40:21.060
2.1.3   |2018-02-26 12:16:41.907 |2018-02-28 22:45:48.687
2.1.2   |2018-02-14 19:56:11.837 |2018-02-26 12:16:41.907
1.1.8   |2018-01-24 12:19:06.933 |2018-02-14 19:56:11.837
1.1.6   |2018-01-08 16:54:46.780 |2018-01-24 12:19:06.933
```

Anyone have some ideas?

Thanks in advance

Petr

DATA:

```
--POPULATE DATA FOR TEST

drop table #temp

create table #temp
(varVersion VARCHAR(100),
dateLoginTime DATETIME)

INSERT INTO #temp (varVersion, dateLoginTime) 
values 
('2.1.4','2018-03-13 11:31:26.893'),
('2.1.4','2018-03-12 11:22:12.650'),
('2.1.4','2018-03-08 08:40:18.133'),
('2.1.4','2018-03-07 16:45:10.207'),
('1.1.8','2018-03-07 16:40:21.060'),
('2.1.4','2018-03-07 12:28:08.823'),
('2.1.4','2018-03-02 12:21:58.583'),
('2.1.4','2018-03-01 12:20:17.163'),
('2.1.4','2018-02-28 22:49:42.320'),
('2.1.4','2018-02-28 22:45:48.687'),
('2.1.3','2018-02-28 12:26:52.760'),
('2.1.3','2018-02-27 12:21:50.887'),
('2.1.3','2018-02-26 12:16:41.907'),
('2.1.2','2018-02-15 12:35:42.707'),
('2.1.2','2018-02-14 19:56:11.837'),
('1.1.8','2018-02-14 12:39:50.603'),
('1.1.8','2018-02-02 12:34:08.393'),
('1.1.8','2018-01-25 12:18:19.790'),
('1.1.8','2018-01-24 12:19:06.933'),
('1.1.6','2018-01-23 15:01:46.410'),
('1.1.6','2018-01-22 12:12:18.510'),
('1.1.6','2018-01-08 16:54:46.780')



--ORIGINAL STATEMENT

SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10 
        varVersion ,
        MAX(dateLoginTime) dateLoginTime--, MAX(dateLoginTime)--, MAX(login_time)
FROM    #temp
GROUP BY varVersion
ORDER BY 2 DESC

--NEW STATEMENT

SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10 
        varVersion ,
        MIN(dateLoginTime) 'FROM', MAX(dateLoginTime) 'TO'
FROM    #temp
GROUP BY varVersion
ORDER BY 2 DESC

select * from #temp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.  Use lag to get the start and then just search above.

```
declare @T table (ver VARCHAR(10), dt DATETIME);
INSERT INTO @T (ver, dt) 
values 
('2.1.4','2018-03-13 11:31:26.893'),
('2.1.4','2018-03-12 11:22:12.650'),
('2.1.4','2018-03-08 08:40:18.133'),
('2.1.4','2018-03-07 16:45:10.207'),
('1.1.8','2018-03-07 16:40:21.060'),
('2.1.4','2018-03-07 12:28:08.823'),
('2.1.4','2018-03-02 12:21:58.583'),
('2.1.4','2018-03-01 12:20:17.163'),
('2.1.4','2018-02-28 22:49:42.320'),
('2.1.4','2018-02-28 22:45:48.687'),
('2.1.3','2018-02-28 12:26:52.760'),
('2.1.3','2018-02-27 12:21:50.887'),
('2.1.3','2018-02-26 12:16:41.907'),
('2.1.2','2018-02-15 12:35:42.707'),
('2.1.2','2018-02-14 19:56:11.837'),
('1.1.8','2018-02-14 12:39:50.603'),
('1.1.8','2018-02-02 12:34:08.393'),
('1.1.8','2018-01-25 12:18:19.790'),
('1.1.8','2018-01-24 12:19:06.933'),
('1.1.6','2018-01-23 15:01:46.410'),
('1.1.6','2018-01-22 12:12:18.510'),
('1.1.6','2018-01-08 16:54:46.780');

select tt.ver, tt.dt as frm
     , isnull((select min(td.dt) from @T td where td.ver <> tt.ver and td.dt > tt.dt), (select max(dt) from @T)) as too
  from ( select t.ver, t.dt, lag(t.ver) over (order by t.dt asc) as lagVer
         from @T t 
       ) tt 
 where tt.ver <> tt.lagVer or tt.lagVer is null
 order 
    by tt.dt desc;

ver        frm                     too
---------- ----------------------- -----------------------
2.1.4      2018-03-07 16:45:10.207 2018-03-13 11:31:26.893
1.1.8      2018-03-07 16:40:21.060 2018-03-07 16:45:10.207
2.1.4      2018-02-28 22:45:48.687 2018-03-07 16:40:21.060
2.1.3      2018-02-26 12:16:41.907 2018-02-28 22:45:48.687
2.1.2      2018-02-14 19:56:11.837 2018-02-26 12:16:41.907
1.1.8      2018-01-24 12:19:06.933 2018-02-14 19:56:11.837
1.1.6      2018-01-08 16:54:46.780 2018-01-24 12:19:06.933
```